# requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL: No schema supplied

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
    #Downloading All XKCD Comics
url = "http://xkcd.com"
os.makedirs("xkcd", exist_ok=True)
while not url.endswith("#"):
    print("Downloading page %s..." % url)
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
    comicElem = soup.select("#comic img")
    if comicElem == []:
        print("Could not find comic image.")
    else:
        comicUrl = comicElem[0].get("src")
        #Download the image.
        print('Downloading image %s...' % (comicUrl))
        res = requests.get(comicUrl)
        res.raise_for_status()
        imageFile = open(os.path.join("xkcd", os.path.basename(comicUrl)),"wb")
        for chunk in res.iter_content(None):
            imageFile.write(chunk)
        imageFile.close()
    prevLink = soup.select("a[rel=prev]")[0]
    url = "http://xkcd.com" + prevLink.get("href")
print("Done.")
```

Full code is stated above. Full output is stated below.

```
    Downloading page http://xkcd.com...
C:/Users/emosc/PycharmProjects/RequestsLearning/main.py:38: GuessedAtParserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 38 of the file C:/Users/emosc/PycharmProjects/RequestsLearning/main.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/emosc/PycharmProjects/RequestsLearning/main.py", line 46, in <module>
    res = requests.get(comicUrl)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\RequestsLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\RequestsLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\RequestsLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\RequestsLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\RequestsLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 316, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\RequestsLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 390, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '//imgs.xkcd.com/comics/rapid_test_results.png': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:////imgs.xkcd.com/comics/rapid_test_results.png?
Downloading image //imgs.xkcd.com/comics/rapid_test_results.png...
```

I have never ever seen an image link like  (only with 2 backslashes not 4) http:////imgs.xkcd.com/comics/rapid_test_results.png this and BS4 recommends me to use that and I dont know how to solve this error. Typically followed Automate the Boring Stuff with Python book, same code as from that book but shoots this error when I try to scrape the site. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I copied and pasted same code as the book, probably site just doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Put the portion of the code below in a try, except block, it'd run.

```
res = requests.get(comicUrl)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the suggestion ... this one was driving me.

Answer (score 0):

The http:// and https:// protocols are both examples of schemas. Print your URLs before every usage in your code, and check to see if those two are not 1:1 included at the start of your url. Failure to add http://url or https://url will lead to the error as shown, so make sure http:// is added.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to check what the URL starts with

```
if comicURL.startswith("//"):
                continue
```

Answer (score 0):

add "http:"
like this: comicUrl = 'http:'+comicElem[0].get('src')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).